# Access shared folder from lambda function (java)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to access the shared folder which is in ec2 windows. How to access the shared folder from java (lambda function)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you normally connect a Java app on a Linux box to a Windows share? The same technique could be used here.

Comment: Can you please add some code examples or more steps that you tried so far as it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Also I think that @JohnRotenstein already provided a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda functions run outside of Amazon EC2 instances. If a Lambda function is configured to use a VPC, it can access resources within that VPC. However, this is normally done to access databases, load balancers and back-end services.

To be able to access a folder from a Windows EC2 instance, the instance would need to be sharing access somehow, and the Lambda function would need to be able to connect via an appropriate protocol. Windows shares are not native to Linux, so it's probably going to be a hard task to accomplish. Whatever technique you normally use to connect a Java program on a Linux server to a Windows server would probably work here (but I don't know how'd you do it).

An alternative is to **store the files in Amazon S3**, which can be easily accessed from both the Windows EC2 instance and the Lambda function. The Windows instance could upload the files to S3, and then the Lambda function can access them when the function is triggered. This is much easier from a security and access standpoint.